# Magento2 - How to fetch the admin product form data in ajax

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

We are trying to show some information before saving the product via an ajax call.

In this ajax, we need to pass all the product form data.

The initial thought was to serialize the product form. But cannot see the form tag in the product add/edit area.

How can we get this product form data in javascript to pass via ajax?

Comment: Why you not try before save product event observer?

Comment: There already written a validation to check the values. But in case of error, it's hard retaining the changed values.
So now the target is showing the calculated values before saving the product.

Comment: you need to use that only.